# Adding missing data at specific index, Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset with NBA player and ball positions and I want to divide it in 11 datasets each of which will contain the position of the ball, player1, player2, player3, player4 ... player10.

So I divided the dataset originally based on index as such:

```
ball_set = training_set.iloc[0::11,:]
player1_set = training_set.iloc[1::11,:]
player2_set = training_set.iloc[2::11,:]
player3_set = training_set.iloc[3::11,:]
player4_set = training_set.iloc[4::11,:]
player5_set = training_set.iloc[5::11,:]
player6_set = training_set.iloc[6::11,:]
player7_set = training_set.iloc[7::11,:]
player8_set = training_set.iloc[8::11,:]
player9_set = training_set.iloc[9::11,:]
player10_set = training_set.iloc[10::11,:]
```

But then I realized that some of the ball positions for whatever reason are missing so after the first missing ball position this way of splitting the dataset does not work.

I tried to do it by using the column name but problem is that I end up with more player positions than ball positions.

So my question is: What can I do to modify the dataset as such:

Everytime I find that a ball position is missing I add the last known position to where the new one should be and I modify the indexes after that so the every nth element sampling continues to work. The dataset is extremely big and I can't think of a way that won't be too time consuming. Sorry for the difficulty explaining the problem.

```
print(ball.head(10))
    team_id  player_id     x_loc    y_loc   radius  game_clock  shot_clock  \
0        -1         -1  75.32556  5.98097  5.49124      706.62        8.92   
11       -1         -1  76.07296  5.46993  5.15024      706.58        8.90   
22       -1         -1  76.81954  5.19475  4.95356      706.54        8.88   
33       -1         -1  77.57706  5.46789  4.93948      706.49        8.86   
44       -1         -1  78.24726  5.89358  4.89680      706.45        8.85   
55       -1         -1  78.98622  6.39669  4.75053      706.41        8.83   
66       -1         -1  79.75325  6.93706  4.44634      706.37        8.81   
77       -1         -1  80.55254  7.51884  3.98987      706.33        8.80   
88       -1         -1  81.38831  8.14618  3.38672      706.29        8.78   
99       -1         -1  82.26478  8.82324  2.64252      706.25        8.76   

    quarter   game_id  event_id  
0         1  21500491         1  
11        1  21500491         1  
22        1  21500491         1  
33        1  21500491         1  
44        1  21500491         1  
55        1  21500491         1  
66        1  21500491         1  
77        1  21500491         1  
88        1  21500491         1  
99        1  21500491         1
```

After a certain index missing data start to appear and every 11th value is no longer the ball.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
  team_id  player_id     x_loc     y_loc   radius  game_clock  \
0           -1         -1  75.32556   5.98097  5.49124      706.62   
1   1610612748       2547  63.70920  34.45719  0.00000      706.62   
2   1610612748       2736  81.69544  11.30207  0.00000      706.62   
3   1610612748     201609  70.29572   7.46278  0.00000      706.62   
4   1610612748     202355  83.90212  34.19776  0.00000      706.62   
5   1610612748     204020  87.10757  47.84178  0.00000      706.62   
6   1610612742       1717  73.23341  27.90537  0.00000      706.62   
7   1610612742     200826  84.12922  31.64608  0.00000      706.62   
8   1610612742       2585  84.09753  28.95075  0.00000      706.62   
9   1610612742     202083  82.54378  13.31071  0.00000      706.62   
10  1610612742     202718  74.64288  11.58677  0.00000      706.62   
11          -1         -1  76.07296   5.46993  5.15024      706.58   
12  1610612748       2547  63.76077  34.51266  0.00000      706.58   
13  1610612748       2736  81.80397  11.24143  0.00000      706.58   
14  1610612748     201609  70.21050   7.43250  0.00000      706.58   
15  1610612748     202355  83.91800  34.18653  0.00000      706.58   
16  1610612748     204020  87.11137  47.84143  0.00000      706.58   
17  1610612742       1717  73.24258  27.92304  0.00000      706.58   
18  1610612742     200826  84.13441  31.70566  0.00000      706.58   
19  1610612742       2585  84.04476  28.94076  0.00000      706.58   
20  1610612742     202083  82.61667  13.24250  0.00000      706.58   

    shot_clock  quarter   game_id  event_id  
0         8.92        1  21500491         1  
1         8.92        1  21500491         1  
2         8.92        1  21500491         1  
3         8.92        1  21500491         1  
4         8.92        1  21500491         1  
5         8.92        1  21500491         1  
6         8.92        1  21500491         1  
7         8.92        1  21500491         1  
8         8.92        1  21500491         1  
9         8.92        1  21500491         1  
10        8.92        1  21500491         1  
11        8.90        1  21500491         1  
12        8.90        1  21500491         1  
13        8.90        1  21500491         1  
14        8.90        1  21500491         1  
15        8.90        1  21500491         1  
16        8.90        1  21500491         1  
17        8.90        1  21500491         1  
18        8.90        1  21500491         1  
19        8.90        1  21500491         1  
20        8.90        1  21500491         1
```

[image: Here's where the problem occurs]

Comment: You don't need to explain your problem. `print(df.head(10))` and paste the output into your question. That's enough.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I edited the answer but still don't know if you will be able to understand. I want to add the missing data by hand and then rearrange the indexes.

Comment: So you're saying that rows with id -1 _should_ be present at jumps of 11 rows but isn't always, correct?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah that's exactly the problem.

Comment: See how much easier adding some data made things? ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You're right. I am sorry for the poor explanation. There are also players missing but I figure I can solve this the same way that I will solve the ball problem.

Comment: I cannot begin to think of a solution that does not require manually iterating and doctoring your data. No chance can you vectorise this operation, obviously changes made in one place ripple down the data and you can't exactly account for that in a pandas one-liner.

Comment: I still dont understand what missing data mean in your case.

Comment: @Bharathshetty The ball position should be present in every 11th row. But after a certain point it appears to be missing.

Comment: Can you add a sample of that certain point ?

Comment: @Bharathshetty Edited that in.

Comment: @Bharathshetty I want to add the last known position of player id -1 there and rearrange all the indexes beyond that point so the player id -1 index remains divisible by 11.

Comment: Im sorry I still couldnt understand the problem. Which one of the dataset above is the expected output?

Comment: @Bharathshetty The first one.

Comment: Are you looking for just this ? `df[(df['team_id'] == -1) & (df['player_id '] == -1)]`

Comment: Why is it you need the position of -1 ids to be exactly divisible by  11? Is it just do your filters at the start work? You could try using `groupby` on `player_id`, depending on what you are actually doing with it.